# データベースを暗号化する際の暗号鍵の管理

Tags: postgresql, database, sql-server, encryption

Microsoft SQL ServerとPostgreSQLで下記の暗号化を検討しています
（所謂アプリケーション層での暗号化/列レベル暗号化）

- Microsoft SQL Server: ENCRYPTION BY XXでの暗号化
- PostgreSQL：pgcryptoを使った暗号化

**データを暗号化する際にどの組み合わせが一般的なのか教えていただけますでしょうか**

1. 共通鍵
2. 共通鍵＋パスワードでの鍵保護
3. 共通鍵＋証明書での鍵保護
4. 公開鍵＋秘密鍵
5. その他

**鍵は通常DBサーバーとは別のサーバーに置きますでしょうか？どのように鍵を管理するのが一番安全でしょうか**

Comment: 前提として何を暗号化したいのでしょうか？ データベースファイル？ 通信経路？ 保護したい個所を明示していただけたらと思います。

Comment: 「一般的」だとアンケートになるので SO ではあまり好まれないっス。この種の暗号化（＝窃取防止）は「どんな手法で」「何を盗む」かの想定が先で、それなしだと無駄な努力に終わっちゃいます。